# Adding another IAP to already approved iOS app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

I have an iOS app in the appstore, with one non-consumable IAP (a downloadable magazine issue), both approved.

I need to add another non-consumable IAP (another magazine issue) to the app, but want to control the time of availability of this IAP in my app - what's the best way to do this?

Can I set "Cleared for sale" to NO, and then submit the IAP to Apple?

Will they check and approve the IAP based on the submitted screenshot alone, or do they need to be able to test it in the app?

If they need to test it, how can I make sure that it's only available to Apple and not available to the general public, while making sure it's already approved when I want to publicly release it?

How long does it typically take to approve an additional IAP (no new app version)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own questions, from what I found out in the meantime:

> Can I set "Cleared for sale" to NO, and then submit the IAP to Apple?

Already answered by tkanzakic - yes, that's possible

> Will they check and approve the IAP based on the submitted screenshot alone, or do they need to be able to test it in the app?

If "Cleared for Sale" is NO, it means (in my case) that the IAP is not visible in the app at all, not even in sandbox and also not for Apple during the approval.

So Apple must have approved the IAPs based on the screenshots alone. (Maybe this is specific to a Newsstand app, maybe it isn't - I don't know.)

> How long does it typically take to approve an additional IAP (no new app version)?

It took 2 days in one instance (significantly faster than a full app submission during that time, which was around 7 days), 6 days for another instance.

> I need to add another non-consumable IAP (another magazine issue) to the app, but want to control the time of availability of this IAP in my app - what's the best way to do this?

We ended up doing this:

- Created a bulk of non-consumable IAPs (one per issue) ahead of time, before the actual release date of the IAPs, with screenshots only, set "Cleared for sale" to NO
- Apple approved the IAPs for the future issues based on the screenshot
- At the release date, using an (already approved) IAP and set "Cleared for sale" to YES
- Making sure we have enough approved "spare" IAPs left

Comment: Are you sure that Apple wasn't able to see new IAPs in your app by using some kind of their own sandbox which would return all items which are not cleared for sale as if they were?

Comment: We had our own backend, where we also had the related products set as "Not cleared for sale". The backend only returned products that were "Cleared for sale", and we requested the IAP data from Apple only for those products.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set `Cleared for sale` to `NO`, to Apple aprove your IAP is not necessary to set this property to `YES`, once it is approved you can change this property and it will be available to the user

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to clear for sale the in-app purchase right away. You can test it in the sandbox environment, and make it available to the public whenever you want.

The time to approve an IAP is roughly the same as the time to approve a new app version (5-7 days, more or less).

Comment: If "cleared for sale" is NO, does it mean Apple will only approve it based on the provided screenshot, or do they actually have to test it in the app?

The fact that there is already an approved IAP of the same type (a non-consumable downloadable magazine issue) does not matter in terms of approval time for the new IAP? (I think I read somewhere that it will be quicker for subsequent IAP submissions)